# How do I splice two vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, splice

I need to splice two vectors based on a condition that also takes a vector as an argument. Example:

```matlab
vec_cond = -5:5;       % The exact values are calculated differently
vec1     = 0:10;
vec2     = 5:15;
```

I need a resulting vector to be comprised from values out of both vectors based on a condition from the third vector. Let's assume this is the condition: `vec_cond >= 0`

Then if this is true, I want `vec_result` to have values from `vec1` on appropriate indexes, and if not, take values from `vec2` on appropriate indexes:

```py
vec_result = vec1 if (vec_cond >=0) else vec2
```

This is portion of my MATLAB script (original comments were Czech) where I would need to use that:

```matlab
%% Draw output current and voltage characteristics
R       = 100:5:2*10^3;             % Load rezistor          [ohm]
U_2     = R .* (I * 10^(-3));       % Load voltage             [V]
U_1stab = U_LM + U_x + U_2;         % Min. required input voltage
                                    % for stabilization        [V]
U_delta = U_1 - U_1stab;            % Difference between actual and
                                    % min. req. input voltage  [V]
U_2norm = U_1 - U_LM - U_x          % Calculating output load
                                    % voltage based on params  [V]

I_z     = U_2norm ./ R .* 10^3;     % Load current param based[mA]
I_r1    = I * I_z.^0;               % Stabilizator current    [mA]
```

So the condition would be `U_delta >= 0`.

I tried to use a ternary operator, which I found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/44243-ternary-conditional-operator):

```matlab
I_graph = (U_delta >= 0) : (@() I) : (@() I_z);         % Current splice  [mA]
U_graph = (U_delta >= 0) : (@() U_2) : (@() U_2norm);   % Voltage splice   [V]
```

That means that for `I_graph`, if the condition is met, take a constant value `I` and vectorize it, otherwise take values from `I_z` vector. For `U_graph`, if the condition is met, take values from `U_2` vector, otherwise take constant value of `U_2norm` and vectorize it.

But it didn't work, this is what it tells me:

```
Operator ':' is not supported for operands of type 'function_handle'.

Error in vypocet1 (line 52)
I_graph = (U_delta >= 0) : (@() I) : (@() I_z);         % Current splice  [mA]
```

I guess that I might want to use `for` loop, but I'm not sure how it will help me and how can I actually construct the necessary vector using a `for` loop.

Comment: I tried to use ternary operator (if something like that does exist in MATLAB, I found something that might tell that it in fact does), but didn't work: `I_graph = (U_delta >= 0) : (@() I) : (@() I_z); U_graph = (U_delta >= 0) : (@() U_2) : (@() U_2norm);` Found it here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/44243-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: @CrisLuengo I updated the question accordingly as I tried something which didn't work. I can draw a graph in MS Paint to show what I want to achieve. The background is necessary in order to understand the goal. But if you want stripped version - I want to splice two vectors based on a condition, which also takes a vector as an argument. As long as the condition is true, values from one vector are used, otherwise I need values from the other. Python makes this super easy, but I need to format the plot and that seems easier in MATLAB.

Comment: I might also calculate this in MS Excel and export CSV of the values and import them into MATLAB as a matrix. But that might be even more complicated.

Comment: Graphs roughly how I would need to look like: https://ctrlv.cz/WRcr

Comment: @CrisLuengo You want me to delete the electrical stuff that is essentialy core to the calculation? Well, I thought it would be useful. If not, then I'll delete it.

Comment: Also, it is probably a duplicate too, though it might be difficult to find because I wouldn’t know how to call it...

Comment: BTW, as it seems, the turning point seems to be at index `188`: https://ctrlv.cz/RrFC - However I cannot simply assume that it will always be this way. I did deliberately choose a specific value based on a previously calculated result from a list of options, but because I know no way to automate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
vec_cond = -5:5;
vec1     = 0:10;
vec2     = 5:15;
```

You can set:

```
out = vec2;
I = vec_cond >= 0;
out(I) = vec1(I);
```

This uses logical indexing, which is indexing with a logical array.

By the way, the ternary operator you found is an exercise to overload the `:` operator for a specific class to do something that it normally doesn’t do. Note how you use the colon when creating `vec_cond`. This is what the colon operator does normally.

Comment: Gonna try that.